# Change the starting day of the week returned by impala trunc()

Tags: hadoop, impala, cloudera-cdh

I am using impala to find the starting day of the week, like this:
select TRUNC('2018-01-01', "D")

Which gives the start day based on a Monday - Sunday week. Is there any way to change this behavior to give me a Sun - Sat week?

I need to change it for my query only, changing a server or cluster wide setting is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
SELECT TRUNC("2018-04-04", "D") - INTERVAL 1 DAY ;
```

Comment: this won;t actually work because you're not changing the days assigned to each week. If I did this I would get the week start date I was looking for, but it would essentially just be re-labeling the incorrect set of days